# Cleaning the tmp files from opencpu server immediately

Tags: javascript, apache, http-post, http-get, opencpu

I have build a app with some opencpu CORS requests with datasets from the app database. This are sensitive datasets. Unfortunately you can access these datasets after request with die /tmp/{session_id}

Now i want to delete the session files, in best case immediately after request, or after some seconds or minutes.

For the second possibility I have found the

`/usr/lib/opencpu/scripts/cleanocpu.sh`

script. But if I change the min from 1440 for example to 2 min it haven't any influence.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the cron job time for running that scripts in `/etc/cron.d/opencpu`.

By default it's every 10 mins:

```
*/10 * * * * apache /usr/lib/opencpu/scripts/cleanocpu.sh
```

In your case it should be:

```
*/2 * * * * apache /usr/lib/opencpu/scripts/cleanocpu.sh
```

Comment: I have changed it, but the data is still reachable after 2 hours and more